# Math websites/apps for high school students

Tags: secondary-education, mathematical-pedagogy, technology-in-education, concept-motivation

I am undergraduate math student who is interested in being a high school math teacher. I have been given an assignment to present to my class (for a total of about 20 minutes) a teaching tool or a teaching strategy that will enhance students’ (high school students) learning of a *particular* secondary mathematics topic.
For example, I have a friend who is presenting https://www.canfigureit.com/, which can help students better understand and set up geometric proofs.

I don't know any websites/apps to teach mathematical concepts except for  https://www.mathsisfun.com/, but this website is very generic and can be used to teach many different topics.

I was hoping that you can respond with websites/apps that you found helped high school students to discover a *specific* mathematical concept/topic.

Comment: This is a little broad. Do you have any specific mathematical concepts in mind? If you said, "I'm looking for apps/websites that teach geometry", then you might get better answers.

Comment: Have you looked at the NCTM illuminations site?  They have a lot of wonderful  lessons and interactives for grades 9-12.

Comment: Sticking with the geometry theme, a very good general site is [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.com), which has ample resources. Even some stat and algebra stuff. Of course, there's also [Desmos classroom](https://teacher.desmos.com/), which I frequently use with my students.

Comment: @AmyB Thanks for pointing that out. Despite being a subscriber for NCTM (by force, I must say), I wasn't aware of the NCTM illuminations site.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewSansom. Do you use different sites to help students with algebra/trigonometry. (If so), which ones?

Comment: @AfronPie It depends a lot on the class and the topic. Recently I've been using [digital AlgebraTiles](https://technology.cpm.org/general/tiles/) to teach quadratic everything for remote instruction. There are similar resources on NCTM Illuminations. I frequently use Desmos activities. A couple semesters ago, when a class was struggling with logarithms, I used a [digital sliderule](http://www.antiquark.com/sliderule/sim/n909es/virtual-n909-es.html) to make things tangible. Surprisingly, I've never had to teach trig, but while tutoring, PHeT has a nice simulation that helps.

Comment: @AndrewSansom Thanks for sharing those sites. I'm gonna look into them right now.

Comment: Please let us know what you end up using.

Comment: I have checked out all the suggestions in the comments, and spoke with my teacher. I ended up choosing to showcase a couple of PHET simulations including the one Andrew was mentioning (https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/trig-tour/latest/trig-tour_en.html). Thanks everyone for your recommendations!

Comment: @AndrewSansom In the future you should post your answer in the Answer box instead of in the comments -- now this question is officially considered "unanswered" even though your answer was excellent.